# Change SASS variables based on screen width

Tags: sass

Is it possible to change sass variable based on screen width? I want my $font-size to be 1.5rem on tablet and 1.4rem on mobile so my headings change dynamically.

I tried sth like this:

```
$font-size: 1.6rem;

@include respond(tab-big) {
  $font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@include respond(mobile) {
    $font-size: 1.4rem;
  }

$font-size-heading: 4 * $font-size;
$font-size-subheading: 2 * $font-size;
```

Or is there any other way to make this code better:

```
$font-size: 1.6rem;
$font-size-tab: 1.5rem;
$font-size-mobile: 1.4rem;

$font-size-heading: 4 * $font-size;
$font-size-subheading: 2 * $font-size;
$font-size-heading-tab: 4 * $font-size-tab;
$font-size-subheading-tab: 2 * $font-size-tab;
$font-size-heading-mobile: 4 * $font-size-mobile;
$font-size-subheading-mobile: 2 * $font-size-mobile;
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic changing font sizes you could use the css `clamp(min value, dynamic unit, max value)` function.

[Kevin Powell did a nice Video on this][1]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9VF-4euyRo

a sass way to further edit this function would be to set the fontsize with a clamp fuction and put in variables.

```css
/*scss*/

@mixin dynamicFontSize ($a) {
  font-size: clamp(10px * $a, 2vw * $a, 20px * $a);
}

@include dynamicFontSize (2);

/*or*/

@include dynamicFontSize (0.7);
```

for this soution you have to tinker a bit with the units but when you got it its awesome.

Comment: Getting
Message:
    app\assets\styles\base\_mixins.scss
Error: Declarations may only be used within style rules.
   ╷
42 │   font-size: clamp(10px * $a, 2vw * $a, 20px * $a);